# Where is this coming from: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, warnings, unique-key

I try this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-firebase-micro-form-7k92h?file=/src/firebase.js:79-368) and also tried it in VCode locally but can't see where this warning in the log comes from:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `App`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at CurrentForm (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1284:11)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1102:70)
```

I changed the `CurrentForm` Component "Form.js" `map` so the `key` had a unique id using like "npm i uuid" but that was not it.

Comment: Did you try adding an id in the Form in index.js?

Comment: Did you google the error? And look at other posts about this exact issue? Did you look into what keys are in React? Did you check out some examples of how to add key props in required instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add key to `Form` component: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-firebase-micro-form-forked-x6ix5?file=/src/index.js)

```js
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import { Form, Result, Landing } from "./steps";
import { NavigationButtons } from "./components";
import { initialState, dataReducer, DataContext } from "./dataContext";
import { formConfig } from "./consts/formConfig";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DataContext.Provider value={useReducer(dataReducer, initialState)}>
        <Router>
          <Landing path="/" />
          {formConfig.map(({ prevStep, ...props }, index) => (
            <Form
              key={index}
              {...props}
              render={(prevStep) => <NavigationButtons prevStep={prevStep} />}
            />
          ))}
          <Result path="result" />
        </Router>
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Yea thanks I learn JavaScript this was cool with the `index`

Comment: Actually using the index as a ```key``` should be avoided as it might be repeated in other components, so use some value that will be unique.

Comment: @KetanRamteke Do you mean like using uuid?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. here is a really nice article about why it's not a good idea to use Index as a key: https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @KetanRamteke Thanks this feels like that JavaScript Array.prototype.map() `ìndex` propert is usles error-prone and should be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

It is `Line: 18` of `index.js` at this section of code:

```
<Form
    {...props}
    render={prevStep => <NavigationButtons prevStep={prevStep} (ADD KEY HERE)/>}
/>
```

You should add a unique key where I have stated it in your `NavigationButtons` component.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [listValue, setListValue] = useState("");
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const addItem = () => {
    if (!listValue) {
      alert("Please Enter the list name");
    } else {
      setItems([listValue, ...items]);
      setListValue("")
      // return;
    }
 };
 
 return(
 <>
 <div className="todo-add">
        <div className="todo-input">
          <input
            className="todo-input-box"
            placeholder="Add List"
            value={listValue}
            onChange={(event) => setListValue(event.target.value)}
          />
          <i className="fas fa-plus" onClick={() => addItem()}></i>
        </div>
   </div>
   {
   items.map((Elements, index)=>{
   return (
              <div className="todo-input" key={index}>
                <div className="list-added">
                  <h4>{Elements}</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="todo-edits" >
                  <i className="fas fa-edit"></i>
                  <i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
   })
   }
 </>
 )
```

Comment: It is textbook undefined behavior. Member x is not initialized after the constructor, and reading uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.